# Why do we need an application container when deploying a Spring Boot app to Openshift

Tags: java, google-app-engine, tomcat, spring-boot, openshift

It maybe a trivial question for experienced web application developers, but for me as a new developer, I cannot understand that why do we need an application container(like Tomcat or Wildfly) when deploying a Spring Boot web application to Openshift, Heroku, or Google App Engine, etc? My understanding is that Spring Boot already contains an embedded container (Tomcat). Can someone explain this to me? Thanks

Comment: I don't know about Heroku, which has a weird rebuild-itself model, but Cloud Foundry (which works with Heroku buildpacks and can take just a runnable jar) doesn't need an external container.

Comment: I want to know why some require an external application container when Spring Boot already contains an embedded application container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringBoot is Java API that relies on an embedded Java Servlet engine to support the API calls. These dependencies are typically pulled in by Maven as dependencies. So for the end user, it just looks like a FAR JAR with a bunch dependencies included (where one of those dependencies is Embed Tomcat, Jetty or Undertow for example)

More information can be found on the main [SpringBoot project page](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).